# How to insert changing schema json into mysql using python3?

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x, api

I have been pulling data from API using python, the data i am getting from api is in nested json for so when i pull the data first time i get it something like this

```
{
"id":4657,
"type":"Media",
"custom_fields":{
"regarding":"await",
"cf_arc":"nodetails",
"cf_bbv":"nodetails",
"cf_mcp":null,
"cf_tte":"nodetails",
"cf_pod":"nodetails",
"cf_mod":null,
},
"createddate":"2019-10-17T09:59:30Z",
"updateddate":"2019-10-17T09:59:30Z",
}
```

if you see custom field is nested json so i want to get these nested json into column single column for each field. so i flatten the json and started inserting into mysql DB

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            # i = 0
            # for a in x:
            #     flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
            #     i += 1
            out[name[:-1]] = str(x)
            # print(x)
            # out[name[:-1]] = x
            # if len(x)==0:
            #   out[name[:-1]] = None
            # else:
            #   out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

my problem is json schema is keep changing and order of columns as well something i get json like

```
"createddate":"2019-10-17T09:59:30Z",
"custom_fields":{
"regarding":"await",
"cf_arc":"nodetails",
"cf_bbv":"nodetails",
"cf_mcp":null,
"cf_tte":"nodetails",
"cf_pod":"nodetails",
"cf_mod":null,
},
"type":"Media",
"updateddate":"2019-10-17T09:59:30Z",
}
```

columns order has been changed so when i flatten the json and try to insert so getting error.

I google the same issue but couldn't get any help i am using python3 and pymysql to insert the data into mysql.

any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the set of valid field names,
and then CREATE TABLE with columns having those names.
You may find it convenient to make two passes over your data,
perhaps storing it in a temp file.
First pass finds the field names and does CREATE TABLE,
second pass does the INSERTs.

You problem becomes much simpler if your table columns are sorted alphabetically.

When inserting, just use this expression to build your list of values:

```
d = flatten_json(y)
vals = [d.get(col)
        for col in sorted(table_column_names)]
```

Notice that if a field is missing for one of those INSERTs,
the `.get()` will default it to `None`.
If we used `d[col]` instead then a fatal error would be raised
when a row is missing a field, which you might find preferable.

EDIT

To produce a mysql timestamp from a string input,
use [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

For example: `str_to_date('2019-07-30T15:25:19Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')`

Comment: can i do it without flatten json like : cursor.execute("INSERT INTO db.tb1(col1,col2) values (%s,%s),((d[custom_fields][cf_arc],d[custom_fields][cf_bbv])),

Comment: You are certainly free to store raw json as a VARCHAR column, yes. You mentioned mysql -- if you're willing to use postgresql you might appreciate the native support for columns of type JSON.

Comment: i would love to you use postgres but i have diff case so bound to use mysql anyways thank for help. still wondering how to do this.

Comment: can you just tell me how to store timestamp '2019-07-30T15:25:19Z' in msql m getting error that "Incorrect datetime value: '2019-07-30T15:25:19Z' for column 'created_at' at row 1") while insertion in mysql.